# Subquery More Than One Row

Tags: mysql, count

i got a problem with my query. I will give my table data, i have 4 tabel: tutor, absen_user, absen, aktivitas

table tutor

```
| id_tutor | nama   | 
| 1        | budi   |
| 2        | Gerald |
```

table absen_user #this table as a bridge of various types of user tables

```
| id_absen_user | id_anak_or_tutor | type  |
| 1             | 1                | tutor |
| 2             | 2                | tutor |
| 3             | 3                | child |
```

table absen

```
| id_absen    | id_aktivitas | id_absen_user | absen |
| 1           | 1            | 1             | Hadir |
| 2           | 2            | 1             | Hadir | 
| 3           | 3            | 1             | No    |
| 4           | 4            | 1             | Hadir |
| 5           | 1            | 2             | no    | 
| 6           | 2            | 2             | No    |
| 7           | 3            | 2             | Hadir |
| 8           | 4            | 2             | no    |
```

table aktivitas

```
| id_aktivitas | tanggal    |     
| 1            | 2018-02-19 |
| 2            | 2018-02-20 |
| 3            | 2018-02-21 |
| 4            | 2018-03-01 |
```

then the result I want

```
| nama    | Februari |
| budi    | 67       |
| gerald  | 33       |
```

data in februari comes from the 'count(absen) with codition field 'Hadir' / count(absen) * 100' ... and this is my query

```
SELECT nama,
       ifnull((
            SELECT ROUND(SUM(CASE absen
                            WHEN 'Hadir'
                                THEN 1
                            ELSE 0
                            END) / COUNT(absen) * 100)
            FROM (tutor)
            JOIN absen_user ON absen_user.id_anak_or_tutor = tutor.id_tutor
            JOIN absen ON absen.id_absen_user = absen_user.id_absen_user
            JOIN aktivitas ON aktivitas.id_aktivitas = absen.id_aktivitas
            WHERE (
                    (Month(aktivitas.tanggal) = 2)
                    AND (YEAR(aktivitas.tanggal) = 2018)
                    )
            GROUP BY tutor.nama
            ), 0) AS `Februari`
FROM tutor
```

and the error i get `subquery return more than 1 row`

Comment: Please format your query to be more readable. Also, describe your "problem" and expected output.

Comment: looking to your code .. why you are uisng a subquery ? .. seems unuseful

Comment: Please explain to us what you are trying to do here as it's not at all clear from your code. This feels very much like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: because in my subquery I want to display data by date.

Comment: I think we'll get a lot farther here if you can share some sample data and your desired results so we can help out. Your query makes no sense as-is. What is wrong with your subquery (by itself) that doesn't show "data by date"?

Comment: I've tried to explain it to my post. I hope it can be understood @JNevill

Comment: The subquery groups on nama yet it returns multiple rows according to the error. It appears that you need to correlate it with the outer query with tutor.

Comment: How? I do not quite understand how to do it. can you give me an example? @shawnt00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT nama,
    ifnull((
            SELECT ROUND(SUM(CASE absen
                WHEN 'Hadir' THEN 1ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) * 100)
            FROM tutor t2
            JOIN absen_user ON absen_user.id_anak_or_tutor = tutor.id_tutor
            JOIN absen ON absen.id_absen_user = absen_user.id_absen_user
            JOIN aktivitas ON aktivitas.id_aktivitas = absen.id_aktivitas
            WHERE
                Month(aktivitas.tanggal) = 2
                AND YEAR(aktivitas.tanggal) = 2018
                AND t2.nama = tutor.nama
        ), 0) AS `Februari`
FROM tutor
```

What you appear to be doing is you wanted to see zeroes even where tutors had no data available for February. This is can be accomplished by outer joins.

```
SELECT nama,
    ROUND(SUM(
        CASE absen
            WHEN 'Hadir' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
             / COUNT(*) * 100) AS Februari
FROM absen_user
    JOIN absen ON absen.id_absen_user = absen_user.id_absen_user
    JOIN aktivitas ON aktivitas.id_aktivitas = absen.id_aktivitas
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN tutor ON absen_user.id_anak_or_tutor = tutor.id_tutor
WHERE
        Month(aktivitas.tanggal) = 2
        AND YEAR(aktivitas.tanggal) = 2018
```

Comment: thanks bro, you save my day :').  can you explain why the group usage does not work, and it just needs to put it into clauses?

Comment: Well you still have the summation over the whole set of rows which is sort of like saying `group by *`. I'm guessing you were picturing grouping as doing what the correlation is actually doing. You need a scalar result there whereas a query with `group by` always has the potential to return more than one (if it's not redundant in the first place.)